# Not able to save results of a loop in list in R for gmodels crosstab

Tags: r, pivot-table

I am running a crosstab with `gmodels CrossTable()` function for a list of columns.
So I wrote a small function to iterate over some columns and store the
results, however, the list appears not to be storing; everything prints to the
screen. Below is my script:

```
# the feature columns to iterate over
features <- c("v1", "v2", "v3" ... "vn")

# function to do crosstabs with gmodels
gtable <- function(x, y, xlab, ylab){
  gmodels::CrossTable(x, y, digits=1,
                      prop.r=TRUE, prop.c=FALSE, prop.t=FALSE,
                      prop.chisq=FALSE, chisq=FALSE,
                      format="SPSS",
                      dnn=c(xlab, ylab))
  }

# store iteration in a list
gtable_list <- list()
for (i in features){
  (gtable_list[[i]] <- gtable(x=df[[i]], y=df$ISMIN, 
                             xlab=var_lab(df[i]), ylab=var_lab(df$ISMIN)))
  }
```

**NOTE**: `var_lab()` is a function from the `expss` library that attaches the variable labels to each crosstable

The `gtable_list` returns NULL when I check it in RStudio.

Comment: This looks like a bug. After a look at the source code `gmodels::CrossTable` does not return the statistics if `format=SPSS` but instead returns NULL. If the format of the printed table isn't important you could use the default SAS format to get your results.

Comment: I don't see any data. So from your description you should be applying `var_lab` to the results of gtable's output rather than as a parameter. But without data that just speculation. Need [MCVE]

Comment: @stefan thanks. After changing the format of the printed table, it's saving now. The format of the table is not that important to me.